# How can I put a prefix on every information outputed from GDB?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb

I would like to put a prefix, like "GDB> ", on every output from gdb to distinguish it from the output of my program.

Is that possible?

An example:

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *p = NULL;

    printf("Test begins...\n");

    p[0] = '\0'; // Forcing a segmentation fault.

    printf("Test finished.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Debugging with this command line:

```
$ gdb -q -ex "set confirm off" -ex run -ex quit --args ./test
```

The output is:

```
Reading symbols from ./test...
Starting program: /home/me/tst/test
Test begins...

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040113b in main ()
```

What I have in mind is set the output to something like that:

```
GDB> Reading symbols from ./test...
GDB> Starting program: /home/me/tst/test
Test begins...
GDB> 
GDB> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
GDB> 0x000000000040113b in main ()
```

Comment: It might be easier to change the output of your program.

Comment: You might want to try [`gdb -batch`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html#index-_002d_002dbatch), or even [`gdb -batch-silent`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html#index-_002d_002dbatch_002dsilent).

Comment: @Bodo yes, but its not a good ideia change my code to fit with a debugger.

Comment: @ssbssa the --batch is good, but just for shorten the command line from `gdb -q -ex "set confirm off" -ex run -ex quit --args ./test` to `gdb -q --batch -ex run --args ./test`. Both --batch and --batch-silient will skip the "header" reading symbols and starting program message, but the rest remain the same. And one (little) detail, with --batch gdb don't show colored messages.